# Mongo DB Authentication failed

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I connected the mongo db with laravel and i tried to get data from collection. but saw below error. Please help me  AuthenticationException in Find.php line 180: Authentication failed.

I tried this also,
use admin

```
{user:"admin",pwd:"admin",roles:["root"]}
```

Comment: what laravel version is that?

Comment: also mongo version and php version? and some details about how did you configure the connection in your config files :)

Comment: laravel version 5.2

Comment: Did you specify the mongo database you are connecting to? Users may be restricted to specific dbs

Answer (score 0):

Use an ORM package like: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/

Make sure you configure the database config correctly for Mongo < or > 3. e.g. 'database' not 'db' for options section in connection config for mongo 3